# How can I receive full-screen notifications when video and audio calls are requested like a Facebook messenger in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am going to develop a video and audio calling app by flutter. Now I am facing a problem detecting notifications with customization like message call / what's app calling. On the other hand, I want to trigger a call event even it is in background mode or terminated, or lock screen. I was tried manually by flutter but no luck. I used flutter_local_notification and awesome_notifications. But it does not satisfy me. Can anyone give me some guidelines to implement it? I want to implement it for both android and ios.

Does need native channeling? If need can share some examples.

Also is it possible to implement by flutter itself?

Thank you.

Comment: On iOS you should integrate with CallKit and use VoIP pushes.  When your app receives a VoiP push it calls `reportIncomingCall` to trigger the system incoming call notification or screen depending on the state of the device

Answer (score 3):

Couple of days ago I have posted for flutter background service.Basically I wanted to build a messenger app .Where the phone call can be trigger for any situation.like foreground, background even app locked or killed.

So ,I have just tried to solve it.Here I did not rely on flutter packages.I have tried to write java code for android specially. I have worked with service and broadcast receiver.Also I had to work with native channeling as well.Now it is working with android.

Key Features:

- Reject/ Answer button
- Ringtone for 30 second.
- If reject/ answer the call,  the service will be stopped and the ringtone will be stopped as well.
- If answer call then redirects to flutter calling screen.
- Working notification and ringtone for app lock mode also.
- I can not video for lock mode. But it is working properly.

Github : https://github.com/Hasib74/flutter_icoming_call_example.git